# qemu fatal on ARM when multiply constant

Tags: arm, constants, qemu, multiplication

I am using QEMU to emulate ARM core. When I multiply with constant, the system report errors

```
qemu: fatal: IO on conditional branch instruction
```

And the instruction is

```
55f8:a8bd8030 
ldmgeia sp!, {r4, r5, PC}
```

it comes from

```
x = x - round * 3.1416 - 3.1416;
```

When I replace the 3.1416 with some variables then the error is avoided. But this is still some potential problem. What could be the reason for it? Is is due to host machine?

Comment: When error occurs the register set areR00=3ff00000 R01=00000000 R02=00000014 R03=00000034
R04=000003fe R05=00000000 R06=c0000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=18069ec4
R12=f8d27aaa R13=18069e7c R14=0000493c R15=000055f8

Comment: please edit the question so the format will be as it should